# Lucene.net with Entity Framework 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, lucene.net

I'm planing to implement a Free text search using Lucene.net and also I'm new to Lucene. In our project we've used ASP.net MVC 3.0 and Entity Framework 4.1.

1. Is it a good decision to use Lucene over free text search in MS SQL server ?
2. What are the implecations that I need to take care?
3. Is it possible to use MS SQL Sever to store indexed documents in Lucene over file system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good decision to use Lucene over free text search in MS SQL
>   server ?

It depends on the amount of data and the query flexibility you want. If you have a large amount of data and you want very flexible queries, yes it is.

> What are the implecations that I need to take care?

You will need to manually keep your lucene indexes up to date with the database, and you will need to handle the free text search yourself.

> Is it possible to use MS SQL Sever to store indexed documents in
>   Lucene over file system ?

see http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Can_I_store_the_Lucene_index_in_a_relational_database.3F

I'd recommend you to take a look at the [Lucene java FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Lucene_FAQ), pretty much everything there applies to Lucene.NET as well and it adresses lots of other questions you may have.